# App crashes when trying to load image from SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, numberformatexception

In my app I have a few EditText's that users can fill in and hit save and it will save those details. I also have a button that opens up a blank canvas for the user to sign on (digital signature).  Then when the user selects save the image is displayed in an ImageView, and then finally the user can tap on save again to save the form with the image. All of this works, but as soon as the user selects save to save the form the app crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.widget.ImageView$ImageViewBitmapDrawable@efa14f0"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
at com.pta.sign.form.CreateFormActivity.persistPerson(CreateFormActivity.java:413)
at com.pta.sign.form.CreateFormActivity.onClick(CreateFormActivity.java:245)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is the code I use:
**FormDBHelper.class**

```
public static final String USER_SIGNATURE = "signature";
....
USER_SIGNATURE + " BLOB, " +
....
public boolean insertPerson(String customername,
                            ......
                            byte customersign, int 
                            jobnumber) {

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

 contentValues.put(NAME_CUSTOMER, customername);
 ....
 contentValues.put(USER_SIGNATURE, customersign);
 contentValues.put(USER_JOB_NUMBER, jobnumber);

    db.insert(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public boolean updatePerson(Integer id,
                            String customername,
                            ....
                            byte customersign,

                            int jobnumber) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NAME_CUSTOMER, customername);
    ....
    contentValues.put(USER_SIGNATURE, customersign);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_JOB_NUMBER, jobnumber);

    db.update(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return true;
}
```

Then in my **CreateFormActivity.class**

```
private FormDBHelper dbHelper;
EditText nameCustomer;
....
ImageView signatureImage;
Button saveButton;
LinearLayout buttonLayout;
Button editButton, deleteButton;
int personID;

.....

nameCustomer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCustName);
....
signatureImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.custimagesig);

....

 dbHelper = new FormDBHelper(this);

    if (personID > 0) {
        saveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        rs = dbHelper.getPerson(personID);
        rs.moveToFirst();
        String customerName = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(FormDBHelper.NAME_CUSTOMER));
        ....
        byte[] custsign = rs.getBlob(rs.getColumnIndex(FormDBHelper.USER_SIGNATURE));

 int personAge = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex(FormDBHelper.PERSON_JOB_NUMBER));
        if (!rs.isClosed()) {
            rs.close();
        }

        nameCustomer.setText(customerName);
        nameCustomer.setFocusable(false);
        nameCustomer.setClickable(false);

        ....

        signatureImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        signatureImage.setFocusable(false);
        signatureImage.setClickable(false);

  .....

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.saveButton:
            persistPerson(); **This is where is crashes (245)**
            return;
        case R.id.editButton:
            saveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            nameCustomer.setEnabled(true);
            nameCustomer.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            nameCustomer.setClickable(true);

            ....

            signatureImage.setEnabled(false);
            signatureImage.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            signatureImage.setClickable(false);

   ......

 public void persistPerson() {
    if (personID > 0) {
        if (dbHelper.updatePerson(
  personID, 
  nameCustomer.getText().toString(),
  ....
  (byte) Integer.parseInt(signImage.getDrawable().toString()),
  ....
  Integer.parseInt(jobEditText.getText().toString()))) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form Update Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentJob.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form Update Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        if (dbHelper.insertPerson(
 nameCustomer.getText().toString(),
 ....
 (byte) Integer.parseInt(signImage.getDrawable().toString()), **this is where it crashes (413)**

                Integer.parseInt(jobEditText.getText().toString()))) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not Insert Form", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentFormJob.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is my code (in the same class) where the user taps on the button to create their signature:

```
Button.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(CreateFormActivity.this, CaptureUserSig.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                data.getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0,
                data.getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
        signatureImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 512, 512, false));
    }
}
```

}

AFAIK this should work, unless I have made a mistake somewhere along the line.  But for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.widget.ImageView$ImageViewBitmapDrawable@efa14f0"`... It clearly tells you that the string `"android.widget.ImageView$ImageViewBitmapDrawable@efa14f0"` is not a valid integer.

Comment: I realize that, but i have hit a blank on how to resolve this issue.  I know that i am doing something wrong by saving the image to the database, and possibly displaying the image again.

Comment: Why would you want to save an image into an SQLite database?

Comment: You're probabbly saving a string, instead of getting the contents of an image and converting it to Base64. By the way, this is a **horrible** practice (also known as an *anti-pattern*). You should store and retrieve only the **path** to the image. Then open that path in your app.

Comment: I've trimmed out an explicit request to "help you out with the correct code" - note that requests for something that can be typed in verbatim is usually interpreted as a request for free work, and may close as too broad. It's much better to assume that an answer will point you in the right direction, and then you can make the final effort to integrate that into your work.

Comment: A better solution is to receive the image from a uri or from your assets. As the previous posters mentioned, it's bad practice to store images in a DB.